# LINQ dropping results

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

I am trying to convert a complex (and rather hacky) dynamic SQL query in to a LINQ query.

I have the following LINQ query so far:

```
var results = (
    from c in Customers
    from d in MonthCalendar
        join f in Facilities on c.CustomerCode equals f.CustomerCode
        join p in ProjectedCashFlows on f.FacilityId equals p.FacilityId into pj
                from p in pj.DefaultIfEmpty()                      
        where d.ExpectedYear == currentYear 
                && f.FacilityStatusId == 1
                && (p.ExpectedYear == null || d.ExpectedYear == p.ExpectedYear)
                && (p.ExpectedMonth == null || d.ExpectedMonth == p.ExpectedMonth)
                && c.PrimaryArmId == userId 
                && (p.ProjectedCashFlowStatusId == null || p.ProjectedCashFlowStatusId != 4)
        select new 
            {
                CustomerCode = c.CustomerCode,
                CustomerName = c.CustomerName,
                FacilityId = f.FacilityId,
                FacilityDescription = f.FacilityProductDescription,
                FacilityCurrency = f.FacilityCurrencyId,
                FacilityLimit = f.Limit,
                ExpectedYear = d.ExpectedYear,
                ExpectedMonth = d.ExpectedMonth,
                ExpectedAmount = p == null ? 0 : (double)p.ExpectedAmount

            }
            );
```

I am trying to retrieve details from a `Customer` table that has a one-to-many relationship with a `Facilities` table. I am then trying to retrieve any details located in the `ProjectedCashFlows`

The problem I am having is that the query should return all `Customer` and `Facilites` information regardless of whether any values exist in the `ProjectedCashFlows` table.

Unfortunately this query is not doing that - it is only returning `Customer` and `Facilities` information when the Facility exists in the `ProjectedCashFlows` table.

I have used a `MonthCalender` table to list out each month in the year.

The relevant table information is:

**Customers**

- CustomerCode
- CustomerName
- PrimaryArmId

**Facilities**

- CustomerCode
- FacilityId
- FacilityCurrencyId
- FaciliyLimit
- FacilityDescription

**ProjectedCashFlows**

- CustomerCode
- FacilityId
- ExpectedYear
- ExpectedMonth
- ExpectedAmount
- ProjectedCashFlowStatusId

**MonthsCalendar**

- ExpectedMonth
- ExpectedYear

As an example I have a customer that has 4 rows in the `Facilities` table however, 2 of these facilities do not appear in the `ProjectedCashFlows` table so they are not being displayed.

If an entry doesn't exist in `ProjectedCashFlows` it should take the ExpectedMonth & ExpectedYear from the `CalendarMonths` table, return 0 for the ExpectedAmount and use the FacilityId from the `Facilities` table.

As you can probably work out I have just started to use LINQ.

Can anyone poke me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query uses `p` *assuming it is non-null*:

```
where d.ExpectedYear == currentYear 
      && f.FacilityStatusId == 1
      && (p.ExpectedYear == null || d.ExpectedYear == p.ExpectedYear)
      // etc
```

But you've used `DefaultIfEmpty()` which will logically create a sequence with a single null value when there are no ProjectedCashFlows.

So basically you need something like:

```
where d.ExpectedYear == currentYear 
      && f.FacilityStatusId == 1
      && (p == null ||
          ((p.ExpectedYear == null || d.ExpectedYear == p.ExpectedYear)
          // etc
          ))
```